# Anyone know whats wrong with this foreach loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made super simple code to generate data from database using Codeigniter. The data was displaying on my view but there is some problem. Each record was generated 9 times. Example i have data id database with name : John Doe, email : john@doe.com, Birthdate: xxxx-xx-xx it was looping 9 times.

Here is the model :

```
<?php

class Transaction extends CI_Model
{
    function getdata()
    {
        $this->db->select('name, email, schools_name');
        $this->db->from('employee, schools');
        $r = $this->db->get();
        return $r;
    }
}
```

the controller :

```
<?php

class Layer extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('transaction');
        $data['data'] = $this->transaction->getdata();
        $data['title'] = 'This is title';
        $this->load->view('test', $data);
    }
}
```

And view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Check</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo heading($title, 1);
            foreach (($data->result()) as $row)
            {
                echo '<p>Name: ' . $row->name . 'and <br> Email: ' . $row->email . '<br> Schools: '.$row->schools_name.'</p>';
            }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Maybe i'm too tired i just cant found what causing this. :D

Many thanks,

Edit : 
var_dump result with limit 1 :

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#20 (3) { ["name"]=> string(16) "Braxton Amundson" ["email"]=> string(18) "braxam27@gmail.com" ["schools_name"]=> string(21) "Penn State University" } }
```

Comment: What is data? Is it an array or an object? You're using it like an array in the controller, but an object in the view. Don't you mean to say `$data['data']->result()?`"

Comment: Why do you have `$data->result()` in parentheses?

Comment: whats this? `$this->db->from('employee, schools');`? are you sure you want 2 tables?

Comment: An object, even i change to 'r' it still populated 9 times per record.

Comment: why are you using this `(($data->result())` piece of code in View? it suppose to be in the model. You are mixing the 'data' array with object.

Comment: @Ghost yes i want 2 tables.

Comment: What does `var_dump($data->result());` produce?

Comment: @MarkM object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)#19 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> object(mysqli)#14 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(270) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(6) "5.6.20" ["server_version"]=> int(50620) ["stat"]=> string(136) "Uptime:....

Comment: Its not readable. Please update your question and put this piece of code there.

Comment: If you're going to be selecting from two tables, you're going to need a $this->db->join() statement in there somewhere.

Comment: @MichaelO'Brien Can show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to select from two tables which is not allowed :

```
$this->db->from('employee, schools');
```

You must update your code to choose the correct (One) table based on selected fields. If you want to use both tables , then you must go to (Join) strategy such as (Inner Join) and link both tables with certain key or value.

You can use the (Join) via :

```
$this->db->join();
```

Which is explained well [(Here)](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) . Hope you find this helpfull.

Comment: I use Query "SELECT employee.name, employee.email, schools.schools_name FROM employee, schools" and not using AR before, but its still.

Comment: @Nucleo1985 I think your logic is totally wrong. The good way to solve your issue is to have Join concept understood well from your side. As I say on my answer your query using ActiveRecord is WRONG. I prefer to put it as SQL ($this->db->query("Your Sql here"));) in case you think your query mentioned in your comment is matching your criteria.

Comment: You are right, i use join and now its work. $this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('schools');
$this->db->join('employee', 'employee.name = schools.schools_name', 'right');
return $this->db->get();